# session undefined with MongoDB after deploy on render

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, rest, backend

Backend project uses node express MongoDB.

At first run backend in localhost:3000 and frontend run in localhost:5000 Want to use to call the api that will fetch the value of the session. When calling, it will use the api that has been designed in the backend. It will use req.session.userId where userId will be the obj id of the user obtained through the function OAuthCallback. Everything was fine until I deployed the backend in render. When I wanted to run the api, the session.userId value was not found.

**server.js**

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      path: '/',
      httpOnly: false,
      secure: false,
      maxAge: parseInt(process.env.EXPIRE_TIME),
      sameSite: 'strict',
    },
    rolling: true,
    store: MongoStore.create({
      mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URL,
    }),
  })
);
app.use(cors({
  origin: ['http://localhost:5000','https://backend-b1ep.onrender.com'],
  credentials: true,
}));
```

**userRoutes.js**

```
router.get("/cmuOAuthCallback", OAuthCallback);
router.get("/cmuOAuthCallback/getSession", getOAuthSessions);
```

**OAuthController.js**

```
const OAuthCallback = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const code = req.query.code;
  console.log("code from OAuthCallback: ", code);
  const access_token = await getOAuthAccessToken(code);
  console.log("access_token from OAuthCallback: ", access_token);
  const user = await getCMUBasicInfo(access_token);

  // log cmu basic info from access token
  console.log("getCMUBasicInfo: ", user);

  const information = {
    accountType: user.itaccounttype_EN,
    name: user.firstname_EN + " " + user.lastname_EN,
    email: user.cmuitaccount,
    organization: user.organization_name_EN,
    organizationCode: user.organization_code,
  };

  const { accountType, name, email, organization, organizationCode } = information;
  // log information about the account
  console.log("information: ", information);

  try {
    let existingUser = await User.findOne({
      name: information.name,
      email: information.email,
    });

    if (!existingUser) {
      //! save to the database
      const newUser = await User.create({
        accountType,
        name,
        email,
        organization,
        organizationCode,
      });
      
      existingUser = newUser;
    }

    // Check if user session is already set
    if (req.session.userId !== existingUser._id) {
      console.log(`BEFORE SET SESSION OF USER ID: ${req.session.userId} -> ${existingUser._id}`);
      req.session.userId = existingUser._id;

      // Save session to the database
      await req.session.save();
      console.log("req.session: ", req.session);
      console.log("req.sessionID: ", req.sessionID);
      console.log(`AFTER SET SESSION OF USER ID: ${req.session.userId} -> ${existingUser._id}`);
    }

    console.log("session userID: " + req.session.userId);
    console.log(`existingUser: ${existingUser}`);

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  try {
    const adminUser = await User.findOne({
      name: process.env.NAME_ADMIN,
      email: process.env.EMAIL_ADMIN,
      role: process.env.OLD_ROLE_ADMIN,
    });

    if (adminUser) {
      if (adminUser.role === process.env.OLD_ROLE_ADMIN) {
        await adminUser.updateOne({ role: "ADMIN" });
        console.log(`${adminUser.name} role updated to ADMIN`);
      } else {
        console.log(`${adminUser.name} role is already ADMIN`);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Cannot update user role`);
  }

  if (!code) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error(`Invalid authorization code ${code}`);
  }

  res.redirect(process.env.REDIRECT_URL_TO_HOMEPAGE);
});


const getOAuthSessions = asyncHandler((async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (req.session && req.session.userId) {
      const user = await User.findById(req.session.userId);
      if (user) {
        res.status(200).json({ user });
      } else {
        console.error("User ID in session not found in database");
      }
    } else {
      // Handle case where no session or userId exists
      console.error("No session or userId found");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return next(error);
  }
}));
```